# Farkas & Kra Riemann surfaces Proposition III.5.10

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

The question is from Farkas & Kra Riemann surfaces.
I can't make the question self-contained because there're too many definitions, and propositions I need to type. So I'm asking for people who have the book (p.87). But if someone asks for some details and notations via comment, I'll add them.

> **Proposition.** For $g\geq 2$, $q\geq 1$, let $\tau(P)$ be the weight of $P\in M$ with respect to $\mathcal{H}^q(M)$. Let $W_q$ be the Wronskian of a basis for $\mathcal{H}^q(M)$. Set $d = d_q = \dim \mathcal{H}^q(M)$. Then $W_q$ is a (non-trivial) holomorphic $m = m_q$-differential where $\color{\red}{m = (d/2)(2q-1+d)}$.

Proof. We must merely verify that the determinant of the Wronskian $\det[\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_d]$ transforms as an $m$-differential under changes of coordinates. Explicitly, let $\{\zeta_1,\ldots,\zeta_d\}$ be a basis for $\mathcal{H}^q(M)$. Let $z$ and $\tilde{z}$ be local coordinates with $\tilde{z} = f(z)$ on the overlap of their respective domains. Assume that
$$\zeta_j =\varphi_j(z)dz^q = \tilde{\varphi}_j(\tilde{z})d\tilde{z}^q$$
in terms of the local coordinates $z$ and $\tilde{z}$ (so that $\tilde{\varphi}_j(f(z))f'(z)^q = \varphi_j(z)$). We must show that
$$(\det[\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_d])dz^m = (\det[\tilde{\varphi}_1,\ldots,\tilde{\varphi}_d])d\tilde{z}^m.\ (\dagger)$$
But it is easy to verify that
$$\det[\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_d] = \det[(\tilde{\varphi}_1\circ f)(f')^q,\ldots,(\tilde{\varphi}_d\circ f)(f')^q] = (f')^m(\det[\tilde{\varphi}_1,\ldots,\tilde{\varphi}_d]\circ f),$$
which is equivalent to $(\dagger)$. $\square$

I don't understand where the red $m$ comes from. Also, from the last displayed equality, $$\det[(\tilde{\varphi}_1\circ f)(f')^q,\ldots,(\tilde{\varphi}_d\circ f)(f')^q] = (f')^{qd}(\det[\tilde{\varphi}_1,\ldots,\tilde{\varphi}_d]\circ f)$$
from the fact that $\det[f\varphi_1,\ldots,f\varphi_n] = f^n\det[\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n]$ for holomorphic function $f$.

I think the following might imply something...
[image: .]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to delete this post, but it seems many people care about this problem so I post a solution.

In local coordinate $z$, write a basis of $\mathcal{H}^q(M)$ by $\{\varphi_1 dz^q,\ldots,\varphi_d dz^q\}$. Then the Wronskian is by definition
$$W_q(z):=\det\begin{pmatrix}
\varphi_1(z)dz^q & \cdots & \varphi_d(z)dz^q\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\varphi_1^{(d-1)}(z)dz^{q+d-1} & \cdots & \varphi_d(z)^{(d-1)}dz^{q+d-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
So, if we focus on the differential part, then the Wronskian is $m$-differential where
$$m = q+(q+1)+\cdots+(q+d-1) = (d/2)(2q-1+d).$$